RuntimeError: "Timeout context manager should be used inside a task" with pytest-asyncio but works in direct Python execution
Using asyncio and aiohttp in an application I'm building and can't seem to figure out how to get pytest playing nicely.  When I use pytest I always get a
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
If I do the same functions that pytest is calling just in main(), the problem seems to go away.  I uploaded a repo to easily reproduce at https://github.com/bcherb2/async_bug
I have tried just about every solution and hack I can find, and nothing seems to work (nest_asyncio, pytest plugins, etc.)
Here is the failing code:
#api_client.py
import aiohttp
import uuid
import json
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Dict, Any
from loguru import logger

class RetCode(Enum):
    NO_ERROR = 200
    BAD_REQUEST = 400
    UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    NOT_FOUND = 404


class DemoAPIClient:
    """Demo REST client that simulates behavior similar to ANTServerRESTClient."""
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        base_url: str = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
        timeout: int = 30
    ):
        """Initialize the API client.
        
        Args:
            base_url: Base URL for the API
            timeout: Request timeout in seconds
        """
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.timeout = timeout
        
        # Session management
        self._session: Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None
        self._session_token: Optional[str] = None

    async def _ensure_session(self) -> aiohttp.ClientSession:
        """Ensure we have an active session, creating one if necessary."""
        if self._session is None or self._session.closed:
            connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True)  
            self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession(
                connector=connector,
                timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=self.timeout)
            )
        return self._session

    async def close(self) -> None:
        """Close the client session."""
        if self._session:
            await self._session.close()
            self._session = None
            logger.debug("Session closed")

    async def login(self) -> None:
        """Simulate login by making a test request."""
        try:

            test_url = f"{self.base_url}/posts/1"
            session = await self._ensure_session()
            
            async with session.get(test_url) as response:
                if response.status != 200:
                    raise aiohttp.ClientResponseError(
                        request_info=response.request_info,
                        history=response.history,
                        status=response.status,
                        message=f"Login failed with status {response.status}"
                    )
                
                # Simulate session token
                self._session_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
                logger.info("Successfully logged in to API")
                
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Login failed: {str(e)}")
            raise

    async def rest(
        self,
        endpoint: str,
        method: str,
        data: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """Execute a REST request.
        
        Args:
            endpoint: The endpoint path (e.g., '/posts')
            method: HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.)
            data: Optional request body data
            
        Returns:
            Dict containing the parsed response data
        """
        if not self._session_token:
            raise RuntimeError("Not logged in. Call login() first")
            
        session = await self._ensure_session()
        request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
        url = f"{self.base_url}{endpoint}"

        try:
            logger.debug(f"[{request_id}] {method} {url}")
            if data:
                logger.debug(f"[{request_id}] Request body: {data}")

            headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {self._session_token}"}
            
            async with session.request(
                method=method,
                url=url,
                json=data,
                headers=headers
            ) as response:
                response_text = await response.text()
                logger.debug(f"[{request_id}] Response: {response_text}")
                
                if response.status >= 400:
                    raise aiohttp.ClientResponseError(
                        request_info=response.request_info,
                        history=response.history,
                        status=response.status,
                        message=f"Request failed: {response_text}"
                    )
                    
                return json.loads(response_text)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"[{request_id}] Request failed: {str(e)}")
            raise


#conftest.py

import pytest_asyncio
from loguru import logger
from api_client import DemoAPIClient

def pytest_configure(config):
    config.option.asyncio_mode = "auto"


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def api_client():
    """Fixture to provide an authenticated API client."""
    logger.info("Setting up API client")
    client = DemoAPIClient()
    
    try:
        await client.login()
        logger.info("API client logged in successfully")
        yield client
    finally:
        await client.close()
        logger.info("API client closed")



#test_api_client.py

import pytest
import asyncio
from loguru import logger
from api_client import DemoAPIClient


async def ensure_task_context():
    """Helper to ensure we're in a task context."""
    if asyncio.current_task() is None:
        task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(0))
        await task


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_client_setup(api_client):
    """Test basic client setup."""
    logger.debug("Testing client setup")
    assert api_client._session_token is not None
    assert api_client._session is not None
    logger.debug("Client setup verified")


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_post(api_client):
    """Test retrieving a post."""
    await ensure_task_context()  # Try to ensure task context
    
    try:
        response = await api_client.rest("/posts/1", "GET")
        assert response is not None
        assert "id" in response
        assert response["id"] == 1
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Test failed: {str(e)}")
        raise


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_post(api_client):
    """Test creating a new post."""
    await ensure_task_context()  # Try to ensure task context
    
    try:
        new_post = {
            "title": "Test Post",
            "body": "Test Content",
            "userId": 1
        }
        response = await api_client.rest("/posts", "POST", new_post)
        assert response is not None
        assert "id" in response
        assert response["title"] == "Test Post"
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Test failed: {str(e)}")
        raise


async def main():
    """Main function to run tests directly without pytest."""
    logger.info("Starting direct test execution")

    client = DemoAPIClient()
    
    try:
        await client.login()
        logger.info("Client logged in")
        
        logger.info("Running test_client_setup")
        await test_client_setup(client)
        logger.info("Client setup test passed")
        
        logger.info("Running test_get_post")
        await test_get_post(client)
        logger.info("Get post test passed")
        
        logger.info("Running test_create_post")
        await test_create_post(client)
        logger.info("Create post test passed")
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Test execution failed: {str(e)}")
        raise
    finally:
        logger.info("Cleaning up client")
        await client.close()
        logger.info("Client closed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


full trace of one of the failing tests:
________________________________________________________________________________________ test_create_post _________________________________________________________________________________________

api_client = <api_client.DemoAPIClient object at 0x7eeac5875a90>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_create_post(api_client):
        """Test creating a new post."""
        await ensure_task_context()  # Try to ensure task context
    
        try:
            new_post = {
                "title": "Test Post",
                "body": "Test Content",
                "userId": 1
            }
>           response = await api_client.rest("/posts", "POST", new_post)

test_api_client.py:51: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
api_client.py:110: in rest
    async with session.request(
.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:1425: in __aenter__
    self._resp: _RetType = await self._coro
.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:607: in _request
    with timer:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <aiohttp.helpers.TimerContext object at 0x7eeac43b19f0>

    def __enter__(self) -> BaseTimerContext:
        task = asyncio.current_task(loop=self._loop)
        if task is None:
>           raise RuntimeError("Timeout context manager should be used inside a task")
E           RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task

.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py:636: RuntimeError

then just run pytest test_api_client.py and python test_api_client.py.  Why is this failing?  Is there any way to fix this?

Please include the full traceback. Also, what plugins are installed? It might be that you're somehow trying to run the tests in different loops.

Added. I have tried many plugin and pyproject.toml permutations, but without almost any different results.  This code in fact is a recreation (simplified) of the actual project, but with the same failure / same passing test (using main() and not pytest).

You have scope=module, try setting loop_scope too: https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to-guides/change_fixture_loop.html
